# react Js data array

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary

i have data and i have succeeded in calling it but inside the data there is a set i couldn't

i summoned the data correctly title, description and imgUrl by using map function, but i didn't know how to summon array (technologies) in a list

#### Component:

```js
export const ProjectCard = ({ title, description, imgUrl, technologies }) => {
  return (
    <Col size={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <div className="project-imgbox">
        <img src={imgUrl} alt="" />
        <div className="project-text">
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <span>{description}</span> <span>{technologies}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Col>
  );
};
```

#### Data:

```js
export const all = [
  {
    title: "Business Startup",
    description: "Design & Development",
    imgurl: projImg1,
    technologies: ["Html", "Javascript", "Css"],
  },
  {
    title: "Business Startup",
    description: "Design & Development",
    imgurl: projImg2,
    technologies: ["Html", "Javascript", "Css"],
  },
  {
    title: "Business Startup",
    description: "Design & Development",
    imgurl: projImg3,
    technologies: ["Html", "Javascript", "Css"],
  },
];
```

I tried many things and tried to summon her within a group, but it did not work

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can display it as a list -

```
        <ul>
          {technologies.map((tech, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{tech}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```